# Vertical & Horizontal Tables in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Please condider the situation in which there are two tables, `Body` and `File`, in which every record of the first one has zero or more corresponding records in the second one:

```
BodyID | Body
-------------
1      | X
2      | Y

FileID | BodyID | File
------------------------
1      | 1      | A
2      | 1      | B
3      | 2      | C
4      | 2      | D
5      | 2      | E
```

Of course, it is pretty easy to join both tables and get something like

```
BodyID | FileID | Body | File
-----------------------------
1      | 1      | X    | A
1      | 2      | X    | B
2      | 3      | Y    | C
2      | 4      | Y    | D
2      | 5      | Y    | E
```

However, what I would like to be able to do is to transform this same table into an horizontal one, like

```
BodyID | Body | File1 | File2 | File3 | ...
-------------------------------------------
1      | X    | A     | B     | NULL  | ...
2      | Y    | C     | D     | E     | ...
```

where each column is replaced by `NULL` (or any other "meaningful" value) when there are no files. The problem is that I can neither use D-SQL nor cursors. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Look for "sql pivot" on this site.

Comment: Though you would need dynamic SQL or to just hardcode a large number of constant `Filen` columns up to some maximum. You will need to `PIVOT` on `ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY BodyID  ORDER BY File)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you need to convert your rows into columns then use pivot.you can search msdn for pivot.